# Angular universal (SSR) not aware of requests with custom http (rxjs ajax, axios)

Tags: angular, rxjs, axios, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm working in an angular app that uses a custom library to make requests to the server and get data. This library uses rxjs ajax method to make calls and is used by other non-angular apps, that's the reason it's not made as an angular library using angular httpClient.

While the library works on the browser and all requests return the data correctly, there is a problem when I try to make it work with angular universal as the data is not being retrieved on server side, or at least angular is not aware of that. As soon as the app gets rendered and the browser takes control again the requests start working again.

This is an extract of how I make requests in the library

```
export class RestMethods {
  constructor(
    private createXHR?: () => XMLHttpRequest
  ) {}
  private restRequest(options: RestRequestOptions): Observable<any> {
    let requestOptions: AjaxRequest = {
      method: options.method,
      url: options.url,
      body: options.body,
      headers: { ...options.headers },
    };
    if (this.createXHR || options.createXHR) {
      requestOptions.createXHR = options.createXHR || this.createXHR;
    }
    if (options.withCredentials !== null && typeof options.withCredentials !== 'undefined') {
      requestOptions.withCredentials = options.withCredentials;
    }
    return ajax(requestOptions).pipe(
      tap((res) => console.log('res', res)),
      map((res) => {
        let response = res.response;
        return response;
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        let errorData: RestRequestError = errorFormatter(error);
        return throwError(errorData);
      })
    );
  }

  getRequest(url: string, reqHeaders?: any, options?: MethodsOptions): Observable<any> {
    const { headers , ...reqOpts } = options || {};
    return this.restRequest({ method: 'GET', url: url, headers: reqHeaders, ...reqOpts });
  }

  postRequest(url: string, body?: any, reqHeaders?: object, options?: MethodsOptions): Observable<any> {
    const { headers, ...reqOpts } = options || {};
    return this.restRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      body: body,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', ...reqHeaders},
      ...reqOpts,
    });
  }

}
```

and an example of a method:

```
getStores(options?: MethodsOptions): Observable<Store[]> {
    return this.xrest
      .getRequest(
        `${this.mainUrl}/stores?language=${this.languageId}`,
        { ...this.headers, ...options?.headers },
        { ...options }
      )
      .pipe(map((data: any) => data)));
  }
```

I've also tried to use axios, to check if there was any problem with the rxjs ajax method and ssr wrapping it into an observable.

```
private request(options) {
    console.log('axios  request');
    let requestOptions: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      method: options.method,
      url: options.url,
      data: options.body,
      headers: { ...options.headers },
    };

    if (options.withCredentials !== null && typeof options.withCredentials !== 'undefined') {
      requestOptions.withCredentials = options.withCredentials;
    }
    return from(
      axios(requestOptions)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log('axios promise resolved', res)
          return res;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log('error');
          return e;
        })
    ).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        let response = res;
        console.log('axios observable', response);
        return response;
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        let errorData: RestRequestError = errorFormatter(error);
        console.error(errorLog);
        return throwError(errorData);
      })
    );
  }
```

After switching to axios I could find out that the request was actually been made, as the console.log inside then block was printed, but the others inside the rxjs pipe were never reached. So I can guess the problem is that angular ssr is not aware of this request completion.

Is there any way to achieve this?